# Conky taking focus off ubuntu desktop (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, conky, ccsm, focus

Whenever I close all of any open windows, the Ubuntu Desktop is not brought back into focus and the title bar stays blank. Due to this, the key combos, the power key, the media keys dont work.

I found that this problem only exists when conky is running and it takes focus off desktop. Though a right click on desktop solves the issue but it is a bit irritating to do this each time when I close a window.

I already tried to get it out of focus using CCSM but it didnt help.

I also tried to configure conky trying all of these

```
own_window yes
own_window no

own_window_type normal
own_window_type desktop
```

but that too didnt solve the issue.

Comment: I'm encountering the same focus issue. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Nope nothing...

Answer (score 4):

I found solution:
just disable “Hide Skip Taskbar Windows” in **General Settings** in Compiz-config-settings-manager (**ccsm**)
[howto-disable-conky-minimization-on-show-desktop](http://www.khattam.info/howto-disable-conky-minimization-on-show-desktop-2010-09-11.html)

Comment: this problem caused so much trouble for so long! thanks!! it works great with my [conky simple clock](http://askubuntu.com/a/550166/46437)!!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue for years, even adding the window rules in CCSM didn't work. It turns out I was missing `own_window_class Conky` in the conky configuration.

**This worked for me**

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM) if missing, `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.

Then CCSM > Window Management > Window Rules (check to enable), add to the No Focus box

```
class=Conky
```

In Conky configuration file

```
own_window_class Conky
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
```

Restart Conky.