# how to have a clock indicator highly visible?

Tags: indicator, clock, accessibility

The problem is actually the date time is very hard to read on the systray. The font is black with white outline in a blue background, so basically what I see there is just blurred unless I glue my face on the screen...

I am not being able to find any other clock indicator, all results point to the default one...

So, my goal is to place there a very clearly readable image with date and time, without having to change my system font rendering settings that all work great everywhere else! neither set anything like high contrast, I just want to make the clock readable.

How can I add such custom, highly visible, clock?

(the answer may vary from my specific description, til a highly configurable, or at least highly visible, clock indicator)

PS.: this `ksystraycmd --startonshow --hidden --tooltip "Clock" --ownicon --icon "test.png" echo` could help on doing the trick but `ksystraycmd` seems bugged as it won't show any custom icon...

Comment: Try changing the GTK theme. Also, how about using a conky overlay?

Comment: managed to make things show on the desktop but not above windows, still looking for that overlay way :)

Comment: By overlay I meant on/above the desktop. It will solve your problem unless you are in maximized or fullscreen mode.

Comment: I have edited the answer to make conky visible above other windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Conky.

It provides a few themes by default and more themes can be downloaded and installed.

Follow these steps:

1) Install Conky Manager, which provides a GUI that allows you to easily manage Conky configurations:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
```

2) Create a conky config file this way:

```
$mkdir -vp ~/.conky/SimpleDateTimeClock
$cat >~/.conky/SimpleDateTimeClock/SimpleDatetimeClock.cfg
```

and paste this on it:

```
use_xft yes
xftfont Sans:style=Bold:size=10
own_window yes
own_window_hints undecorated,above,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_colour darkblue
gap_x 10
gap_y 30
alignment top_right

TEXT
${color white}${execi 1 date +"%H:%M"}${color grey}${execi 1 date +":%S"}${color yellow}${execi 1 date +" %d"}${color cyan}${execi 1 date +" %b"}
```

Important: there must have no NEWLINE character at the last line or it will be rendered on conky. So the last line must be the one of `execi` commands.

This minimal config is based on [this example](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865&p=1646068#post1646068).

3) Activate it on Conky Manager, and on its settings, enable the clock to be run on startup.

Comment: almost worked! ok I am using conky "miui", the .conkyrc was actually `~/.conky/Conky MIUI/miui`, I had to set it to transparent; but, by using the "above" window hint, it only went above normal windows; it did not went above the unity systray top bar; my idea was to put something above the normal systray clock; conky looks it could do the trick if it stay above unity top bar! not sure if possible tho..

Comment: Remove the `skip_taskbar` label if you want to place it over the taskbar.

Comment: mmm.. I think it is not possible, the unity hud/systray top bar, seems to force being the top most one. the skip_taskbar actually prevents that window being  listed on the windows list only :/

Comment: I made it work! thanks! btw, the `~/.conkyrc` may be something deprecated? it is not on my system even after using conky-manager..

Comment: I will make some edits to reflect my experience, and provide a minimal conky configuration.

Comment: this one looks better `${color grey}${execi 1 date +"%d %b"}${color yellow}${execi 1 date +" %H:%M"}${color grey}${execi 1 date +":%S"}`

Comment: and this one doesnt require execi `${color grey}${time %d %b }${color yellow}${time %H:%M}${color grey}${time :%S}`

Comment: and to fix it from receiving focus and make some global hotkeys stop working, at ccsm [disable “Hide Skip Taskbar Windows”](http://askubuntu.com/a/506604/46437)